# Fetch data from JSON with less code using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, performance

I want to fetch JSON Data and append it to `div` element.

Here is my JSON Data:

```
var data = [{
    "headTitle": "Head_title",
    "head":[
        ["Data", "Data","Data"],
        ["Data","b","c"],
        ["Data","b","c"],
        ["Data","b","c"],
        ["Data","b","c"],
        ["Data","b","c"]
    ],

"tableInfo": [{
    "tableData1": [{
            "col1Text": "tableData1 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData1 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData1 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData1 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData1 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData1 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData1 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData1 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData1 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData1 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData1 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData1 col3Text Data"
        }],
        "tableData2": [{
            "col1Text": "tableData2 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData2 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData2 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData2 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData2 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData2 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData2 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData2 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData2 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData2 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData2 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData2 col3Text Data"
        }],
        "tableData3": [{
            "col1Text": "tableData3 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData3 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData3 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData3 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData3 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData3 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData3 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData3 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData3 col3Text Data"
        }, {
            "col1Text": "tableData3 col1Text Data",
            "col2Text": "tableData3 col2Text Data",
            "col3Text": "tableData3 col3Text Data"
        }]

    }];
```

In above code. I added some information and I want tableData1, tableData2, tableData3 to insert in new line using jquery.

Can anyone please suggest me, how I fetch the JSON data by using less coding (i.e 2 or 3 loops).

Comment: This is a  JS object  not JSON (which would be a string representation of this object). What do you mean by "*how I fetch the JSON data by using less coding*"? Fetch it from where? Are you trying to ask how to loop over this JS object and build a table from it.

Comment: yes. I just want loop over this JS object and build a table from it with minimum iterations of a loop.

Comment: Is this expected to make 3 tables given the data above?

Comment: Can you explain the head?  It has more items than there are tables to be generated.

Comment: @EmmanuelDelay since those are outside the `tableInfo` index, Im thinking `headTitle`  is the html page title and `head` is meant to be an array of resources like `css` and `js` files and not really needed for the table generation, just my assumption though, I could be wrong